# Message Receive ISE 500 Confusion Ruby Sinatra

Tags: json, ruby, nginx, twilio, passenger

I have **Twilio** `SMS` pointing to a webhook.  I'm getting two things:

1. NOT a `JSON` application in content:

```
Content-Type

text/html;charset=utf-8
```

2. The `ISE 500`.  `Passenger` is reporting this issue:

```
App 24776 output: 2023-09-11 23:01:17 - JSON::ParserError - unexpected token at 'ApiVersion=2010-04-01&SmsSid...
```

`Sinatra` is using the following code in a `route` that accepts **Twilio** connections:

```
json_payload = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
log_twilio(json_payload.to_s)
```

That method simply writes it to a log file I created.

How can I find out what's happening and fix it?  I'm expecting `JSON` to be coming from **Twilio**, which I could parse and do whatever I want with it.

Comment: The payload isn’t JSON, see https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-faq#where-do-i-find-the-specifications-for-inbound-http-requests-to-my-server

Comment: Yes I had that in my mind for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out `params` has all that on a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` `request`.

Comment: What do you mean by "all that"?

Comment: All incoming json items (key/value pairs in a Ruby hash).  Represented by params.

Comment: I still don’t understand your question an this answer. What exactly is the problem and how does this answer solve the issue?

Comment: I was thinking the request was a JSON request, when it isn't.  So I don't have to parse them coming in as they are already presented as `params`.